# Perl regex matching emoticons

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to remove certain emoticons from a string, but I can't figure out how to match emoticons consisting of special characters and letters, for example :D or :-D (it works for emoticons like ":-)" ). I tried

`$message =~ s/\:D//;`

and few other variations, but nothing seems to work. Where am I wrong?

EDIT: I was actually stupid and didn't realize I made all the letters lowercase before this command, so all the emoticons were already changed to ":d". Thanks for help.

Comment: That regex works for me. Use the Data::Dumper module and check your input and code. E.g. `print Dumper $message`. And turn on strict and warnings.

Comment: Write a module with tests for it, and upload to CPAN. People would use it, find bugs, write tests, and module would become more and more useful with time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write some unit tests:

```
sub assert_equals($$) {
  my ($expected, $actual) = @_;
  $expected eq $actual or die "expected <$expected>, got <$actual>\n";
}

sub no_smilies($) {
  my ($message) = @_;
  $message =~ s/:D\b//g;
  return $message;
}

sub test() {
  assert_equals("", no_smilies(":D"));
  ...
}
```

Then you can do the rest using trial and error.

Answer (score 3):

```
use strict; use warnings;

my $s = "Hello ;-) :D :-D <3 World!";
my @emoticons = qw' ;-) :D :-D <3 ';

my $pat = join '|', map qr/\Q$_\E/, @emoticons;
$s =~ s/$pat//g;
$s =~ s/ +/ /g;

print "$s\n";
```

Output:

```
Hello World!
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this for starters:

```
s/[:;]-?[D)]//
```

Add characters into the `[]` classes as you discover new and interesting emoticons.

Comment: It just makes sure there is only one of the characters in that class. I suppose it's not essential, but may avoid some false positives.

Comment: Isn't `{1}` redundant?  It requires exactly one match, which is the default when no quantity modifier is present. Am I missing something?

Comment: No, you are right. I'll take it out. It's not necessary. Sometimes my fingers get ahead of my brain :-D

Comment: It won't prevent matching more than one however; for that you'd need to either match something else immediately prior (including start of line) or else use a negative look-behind assertion.